# Find Zip file and a folder that have same name

Tags: powershell

I am trying to locate via PowerShell or other method zip files and folders that have same name.

Staff members unpack their zip files on our storage array and subsequently never delete the zip file. Now we have two copies, the zip file and the unzipped folder.

Via PowerShell, I could find a text and zip file that have the same name, but not a folder and a zip file.

Any help is appreciated. Below is my code.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path c:\temp\test -Recurse | Group-Object -Property Directory, BaseName | Where-Object Count -gt 1 | Select-Object Name
```

Comment: just to confirm i understood correctly, you're looking to find any folder containing a zip file and a subfolder with the same base name of the zip correct?

Comment: You want greater equal 1, not greater.  Hopefully you will only get one that matches.

Comment: `Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse -Filter '*.zip' | ForEach-Object {$Dpath = Join-Path -Path $_.DirectoryName -ChildPath $_.BaseName; if (Test-Path -Path $Dpath) { $Dpath }}`

Comment: If you want the archive file names instead of the directory names: `Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse -Filter '*.zip' | ForEach-Object {$Dpath = Join-Path -Path $_.DirectoryName -ChildPath $_.BaseName; if (Test-Path -Path $Dpath) { $_.FullName }}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming I understood correctly, here is one way you could do it. See inline comments to help you understand the logic.

```bash
# find all `.zip` files recursively
Get-ChildItem c:\temp\test -Filter *.zip -Recurse |
    # where the Parent Directory of this file also has a sub-folder
    # with the same `.BaseName` as this `.zip` file :)
    Where-Object { $_.Directory.EnumerateDirectories($_.BaseName) }
```